# Extract patterns from tuples

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples

```
 a=[('a', 0), ('c', 1), ('d', 0), ('b', 1), ('t',1), ('j',2), ('k',3), ('s', 4), ('l',1), ('y',1), ('r',2), ('b',3), ('k',4)]
```

I want output like

```
 [[1,1,1,2,3,4],[1,1,2,3,4]]
```

and corresponding letters

```
 [['c', 'b', 't', 'j', 'k', 's'], ['l', 'y', 'r', 'b', 'k']]
```

I need to remove 0's in between and the pattern always starts with 1

Comment: Why are there two sublists? I think I'm with you on the "filter out zeroes" bit, but what indicates the decision of when to end a sublist and start a new one is unclear to me.

Comment: The sublists can end with 2 or 3 or 4 but it should always starts with 1. So whenever the next new 1 appears after 2 or 3 or 4 the sublists should starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple loop and tracking the previous non-zero value:

```
letters = []
numbers = []
prev = 2
for l,n in a:
    if n == 0:
        continue
    elif prev > 1 and n == 1:
        letters.append([])
        numbers.append([])
    letters[-1].append(l)
    numbers[-1].append(n)
    prev = n

letters
# [['c', 'b', 't', 'j', 'k', 's'], ['l', 'y', 'r', 'b', 'k']]

numbers
# [[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: In the above code..if I want to include zeros only in the pattern but not before and end of the pattern for eg:[1,0,1,1,2,3,4] .How is it possible!

Comment: You can use a flag that will be set when the first non zeros is found. This enables you to start collecting 0s. To eliminate the end zeros is a bit more difficult as you do not know in advance when you won't see non-zeros. So you can post process to eliminate the trailing ones.